# Parallel lines are either projected onto parallel lines or on two points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, projection

Show that two different parallel lines are either projected onto parallel lines or on two points
by a projection $p_{π,d}$
, where $π : Ax + By + Cz + D = 0, d :
\frac{x − x_0}
p =\frac{y − y_0} q= \frac{z − z_0}r$  and  $π\nparallel d$.

Can somebody help me with this problem, please? I have no idea how to start it even.

Comment: A very similar question has been posed just a few minutes ago by another user. Please check.

Comment: @YNK Well, that question was closed for lack of context, so it’s not going to be of much help here.

Comment: I don’t believe you. You must have _some_ idea of things to try. For instance, under what conditions is the image of a line under projection onto a plane a single point? How do you know that two lines in $\mathbb R^3$ are parallel?